JavaScript not working properly in a certain localhost port using Microsoft Edge
I have the following HTML and JavaScript files. The intention is that when the button is clicked, the user enters their name into a prompted dialogue box, which is then used in the greeting message.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-UK">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="greeting">
        Hi!
    </p>
    <p>Enter your name after clicking the button below to get a personalised greeting!</p>
    <button>Change User</button>
</body>
</html>

let userButton = document.querySelector("button");
let greetingParagraph = document.getElementById("greeting");

function setUserName() {
    const userName = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    if (!userName) {
        greetingParagraph.textContent = "Hi!";
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
        greetingParagraph.textContent = `Hi, ${userName}!`;
    }
};

if (!localStorage.getItem("userName")) {
    setUserName();
} else {
    greetingParagraph.textContent = `Hi, ${localStorage.getItem("userName")}!`;
};

userButton.onclick = () => {
    setUserName();
};

I enter python -m http.server 8000 and python -m http.server 8001 into Windows PowerShell. In Microsoft Edge: in the former port, the button does not work at all - the button is clickable, but nothing happens when it is clicked. In the latter port, the button behaves exactly as desired.
However, in Firefox, the button works as desired in both ports.
Why is the JavaScript not working in the localhost:8000 port using Microsoft Edge? I have searched for an explanation of this issue but have been unable to find anything relevant.
I have also tried reloading the page by pressing F5 which presumably clears the cache for the page, but it has not resolved the issue.

Your code works in Edge & Chrome. In Edge, you can use localhost:80 or 127.0.0.1:80. These are the default ports.
What are you trying to achieve by specifying ports?
Additionally, is this specifically a Python question? If so, you have not phrased it as such.

@foxbeefly I do not have any particular reason for specifying ports. Also, this is not specifically a Python question; I have only included my use of Python in case it turns out to be relevant to my issue.

So then it is important for you to test it without specifying the ports to see if that works. That way you have solved your problem by process of elimination.

F5 reloads the page, normally from the cache.
Ctrl+F5 ("hard refresh") normally bypasses the cache and reloads the page from the server.

@foxbeefly Thank you for your help. Returning to the site after a few days, the issue seems to have resolved itself (though I am not certain that the issue will not reappear). There is no issue when I do not specify the ports.
